# Delphi - Indy TCP ReadStream Synchronize is making app to stop responding

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy

I am trying to create a simple test app for getting remote files using Indy IdTCPServer and IdTCPClient. It is working just perfect for lightweight streams ( less then 1 or 2 MB ), but when ReadStream finish downloading a large file (for example 10 MB) and will save it, app stop responding for some seconds and I get that ugly error on app window title ("not responding").

Ps. I know the freeze occurs when it trying to save the stream (file), because I am using a progressbar to know the download progress.

Here is the code:

```
type
  TSyncStm = class(TIdSync)
  protected
    FStm: TMemoryStream;
    procedure DoSynchronize; override;
  public
    constructor Create; override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TSyncStm.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FStm := TMemoryStream.Create;
end;

destructor TSyncStm.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FStm);
  inherited
end;

procedure SyncStm(const Stm: TMemoryStream);
var
  Sync: TSyncStm;
begin
  if not Assigned(Stm) then Exit;
  Sync := TSyncStm.Create;
  try
    Sync.FStm.LoadFromStream(Stm);
    Sync.Synchronize;
  finally
    Sync.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TSyncStm.DoSynchronize;
begin
  FStm.SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + \files\file01.zip');
  frmMain.FileListBox1.Update;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.TCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  SMsg: string;
  Client: TClient;
  LQueue: TStringList;
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  ...
  // Here I have a working queue method, to process commands
  // when server sends a command 'sendfile' to client, it returns the file (stream)
  ...
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    ReadStream(Stream, -1);
    if (Stream <> nil) then
    begin
      Stream.Position := 0;
      SyncStm(Stream);
    end;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Please, which is the best way for processing and synchronizing the streams, without making app to stop responding?

Comment: You are saving the file in the main thread of the application, this will block the GUI, move the code out of `DoSynchronize` leaving only the update statement for the filelistbox...

Comment: @whosrdaddy: even then, for something as simply as an `Update()` call, I would use `TIdNotify` (even go as far as use `TIdNotify.NotifyMethod()` instead of a derived class). Or, in a modern Delphi version, use `TThread.Queue()` directly.

Comment: I would also use `TFileStream` instead of `TMemoryStream` in `TCPServerExecute()` to avoid caching large files in memory.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, you are nothing but correct! I was just pointing out the obvious bottle neck ;)

Comment: Thank you both for your comments and tips! I will try to implement it and make new tests.